# PHP - can't seem to query data from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables: bound, station and time

Bound has 2 columns: boundID and boundName

Station has 3 columns:  stationID stationName boundID

Time has 4 columns: timeID departureTime tramID stationID

I am using this query to get the boundName but can't seem to get the data. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    $query ="SELECT b.boundName, s.stationName, t.departureTime 
    from Station s, Time t, Bound b 
    where s.stationID = t.stationID 
    AND t.departureTime !=''
    AND s.boundID = b.boundID
    AND b.boundName";  
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: `AND b.boundName` this is not condition;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AND b.boundName at the end shouldn't be there because a WHERE condition evaluates to either 1 or 0 and so the individual statement should also do the same, which definitely doesn't return either 0 or 1 in your statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the last: 'AND b.boundName'.

**Use this:**

```
$query ="SELECT bound.boundName FROM bound, station, time WHERE
station.stationID = time.stationID AND time.departureTime !='' AND 
station.boundID = bound.boundID";
```

**Or this:**

```
$query ="SELECT b.boundName, s.stationName, t.departureTime 
    from Station s, Time t, Bound b 
    where s.stationID = t.stationID 
    AND t.departureTime !=''
    AND s.boundID = b.boundID";
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you use join try this**

```
    SELECT
    `time`.`departureTime`
    , `station`.`stationName`
    , `bound`.`boundName`
FROM
    `test`.`station`
    LEFT JOIN `test`.`bound` 
        ON (`station`.`boundID` = `bound`.`boundID`)
    LEFT JOIN `test`.`time` 
        ON (`time`.`stationID` = `station`.`stationID`);
```